# Android app crashing and I cannot figure out why

Tags: android

I have a very strange bug.  It only happens in the Emulator. I tested it on multiple Android phones and the Acer Tablet, it works fine there.

My program has a loop that loads in Bitmaps into a `Bitmap[] bitCards`. The Array is set up for 14 elements by `bitCards = new Bitmap[14]`.

Now it loops 12 times to put a Bitmap into the Array as follows:

```
bitCards[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

When i = 8 it crashes at this statement.

If i replace it with

```
bitCards[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

it does not crash, I thought maybe somehow the Array was not big enough so I did the following

```
bitCards[8]=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream); // Still did not crash.
```

The only thing that makes sense is that when I have

```
bitCards[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

It is relasing the old memory and putting in a new object, thus only memory for one object is created, but.... the exception does not go off, shouldn't I get some kind of an error?

Here is my full code:

```
void Shuffle()
{
    Random generator;
    generator = new Random();
    int[] iCardsUsed;
    iCardsUsed = new int[55];
    for(int i=0;i<55;i++)
    iCardsUsed[i]=0;

    try {   

        bitCards = new Bitmap[14];
        iCards = new int[14];
        iTurnOver = new int[14];

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            iTurnOver[i]=0;

            int cardId;

            do {
                cardId = generator.nextInt(50);
            } while( iCardsUsed[cardId] ==1);

            iCardsUsed[cardId] =1;
            iCards[i]=cardId;

            iCards[i]=i;    
            String fName=new String("card");
            fName+=Integer.toString(iCards[i]+1);
            fName+=".jpg";

            AssetManager assetManager= ctx.getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = assetManager.open(fName);

            // this is where it crashes
            bitCards[i]=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            inputStream.close();    
        }

    } catch( IOException e)
    {
        gi++;
    }
    // update screen
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: can you provide the error message?

Comment: Please provide the logcat info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have provided no error message, I am taking a shot in the dark and assuming it is going OOM.

You say that it stops after running for a few times ( when i = 8) , I believe that you are not freeing the resources. Bitmaps can sometime take up a lot of space and if you are persisting them in the memory, I would not be surprised if the device goes OutOfMemory. Different devices have different specs for memory and after a few runs it is filling up the memory.

So, my suggestion would be to clear the Bitmaps, using **`mBitmap.recycle()`**,  and the other storage that you are using for temporary purposes.

Also, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)!